# Error when getting property from a state in React rather than an object

Tags: reactjs, object, state

I get an error when trying to call an objects properties that are stored into a react state. If I add the exact roperty to a state it works fint. But if I store the object within my state and try to call the property I get the error message:

```
Cannot read property '_embedded' of undefined
```

This is my code

```js
var axios = require('axios');

    var App = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          warningName: '',
          warningBase: {}
        },     
      }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        var _this = this;
        var help = this.state.dietNames;
        
        axios     
            .get("http://api.baggid.com/users/61113f093cc04421aa3900d53e929d6a/profiles/2850/warninggroups/")
    .then(function(result) {
      _this.setState({
        warningName: result.data._embedded["bgd:warninggroup"][0]._embedded["bgd:warning"],
        warningBase: result.data._embedded["bgd:warninggroup"]
            });
        })

render(){
  console.log(this.state.warningName); //works
  console.log(this.state.warningBase[0]._embedded["bgd:warning"]); //doesn't work
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What error? `Provide whole code block - from code sample `warning` variable is not defined. That seems to be issue here.

Comment: Yes, it is ("Cannot read property '_embedded' of undefined"). But why is it not defined?

Comment: Where are you calling the `console.log` from? It's hard to decipher the problem without the whole code.

Comment: OK, I updated my post and hope it gets clearer